# While focus on input check if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a small function that is getting looped when an input is getting focus and stopping the loop when the input is losing focus. Now I would like to know if there is a better way to write this code.

```
 var timer; 
  function Change () {   
    if( !$('#eventurl').val() ) {

      $("#js-skipbutton").text('overslaan');
      console.log(0);
    }
    else{
      $("#js-skipbutton").text('ophalen');
      console.log(1);
    }
  };
  $('#eventurl').focus(function() { 
    timer = setInterval(Change, 200);
  });
  $('#eventurl').focusout(function() { 
    clearTimeout(timer);
    Change();
  });
```

This code is changing the text to "overslaan" on a span when the input is empty and to "ophalen" when the input is containing text.

Comment: Did you mean `var timer` instead of `var time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cache `$("#eventurl")` and `$("#js-skipbutton")` so jQuery won't search those elements multiple times, that's a little speed up.

```
var eventulr = $(document.getElementById("eventurl"));
var js_skipbutton = $(document.getElementById("js-skipbutton"))
```

It's not necessary to check for `focus` or `focusout` events in an `input` element *(specially the `focusout` event, that is used for event bubbling)*.

Instead, only check for `keypress` event. This way you won't be checking if the `input` element is empty every 200 milliseconds whether the user is pressing a key or not

```
eventurl.on("keypress", Change);
```

---

**Edit**

Since `keypress` event is not triggered when text is pasted into the `input` element you can listen for `keyup` event instead; Which is triggered whenever a key is released *(Including Ctrl, Shift, etc.)*. Or rely on jQuery's `change()` method which works with `input`, `select`, `textarea` elements.

```
eventurl.change(Change);
```